# Get a website's http root with jquery

Tags: jquery, split, jquery-1.9

I want to get the file root's location by using keywords such as below. But both keywords give me different result.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/website/core/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/website/local/ready.js"></script>

$('script[src$="core.js"]').attr('src').split('core')[0];
// get this  --> http://localhost/website/

$('script[src$="ready.js"]').attr('src').split('local')[0];
// get this  --> http://
```

I am after `http://localhost/website/` as my result.

Is it possible to add regex into the split function such as below?

```
$('script[src$="core.js"]').attr('src').split('core|local')[0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression that matches word boundaries, so that `local` doesn't match `localhost`.

```
$('script[src$="core.js"]').attr('src').split(/\b(?:core|local)\b/)[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$('script[src$="core.js"]').attr('src').split(/\/core\/|\/local\//)[0]+'/'
```

What the above does is:

1. Split by `/core/` or `/local/` whichever it finds first
2. Append a `/` at the end since that is not part of the first split